# Python out of sample forecasting ARIMA predict()

Tags: python, statsmodels

Does statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(mylist, (p,d,q)).fit().predict(start, end) only work for d=0?...

myList is a list of 72 decimals all >0, p=2, d=1, q=1, start=72, end=12 and the majority of the forecasts are negative decimal numbers which leads me to believe statsmodels doesn't automatically undifference after performing the forecasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `typ` keyword of predict in the [docstring](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html). It determines whether you get predictions in terms of differences or levels. The default is 'linear' differences not levels. As an aside, your start should not be greater than your end. If this works, then this may NOT be giving you what you want and should probably be reported as a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Glad I have the attention of a statsmodel developer:)... these are the changes I made:predict = fit.predict(start=len(thirtyRR), end = len(thirtyRR)+11, typ = 'levels')

Comment: Was wondering if I could bother you with my full script and get your feedback...I'm trying to replicate a function similar to auto.arima in R using statsmodels (to be used for forecasting literally hundreds of variables at once), but I'm wondering if I'm better off just importing R script using auto.arima through rpy2?

Comment: For large scale automatic order selection, you might be better of using `auto.arima`. I've also exposed autolag from X13-ARIMA in the latest statsmodels, which you might find useful. It outperformed `auto.arima` in my last project where I needed this but I wouldn't say it will always outperform the heuristics in `auto.arima`.

Comment: I should also note that it's limited to monthly and quarterly data. You can see an example [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/release/version0.6.html#wrapping-x-12-arima-x-13-arima). More [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_select_order.html#statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_select_order).